# Proving $||x||_{\infty}$ is a norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that given $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, the following holds

$$
||x + y||_{\infty} \leq ||x||_{\infty} + ||y||_{\infty}
$$

Assume $x = a + ib, y = c + id, a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$
||x + y||_{\infty} = \max_{j} (x_j + y_j) = \max_{j} [(a_j + c_j)^2 + (b_j + d_j)^2]^{½}\\
||x||_{\infty} + ||y||_{\infty} = \max_{j} [(a_j + b_j)^2]^{½} +  \max_{k}[(c_k + d_k)^2]^{½}\\
$$

There are two issues here that I'm not sure how to go about. One is that the second norm depends on two indices ($j$ and $k$). Two, is it possible to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the triangle inequality in $\Bbb C$ to prove this inequality. Suppose $x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,\ldots, y_n)$. For $k = 1,2,\ldots, n$, $$|x_k + y_k| \le |x_k| + |y_k| \le \|x\|_\infty + \|y\|_\infty.$$ Therefore $$\max_{1 \le k \le n}|x_k + y_k| \le \|x\|_\infty + \|y\|_\infty.$$ That is, $$\|x + y\|_\infty \le \|x\|_\infty + \|y\|_\infty.$$